# Getting no logs from Socket.IO's on connection

Tags: reactjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to emit upon any socket.io event, but haven't been able to. I have a react app with frontend and backend, socket.io installed on the backend and socket.io-client on the frontend.

I have a socketServer.js:

```
const registerSocketServer = (server) => {
  const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: "*",
      methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    },
  });

  io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("user connected");
    console.log(socket.id);
  });
};

module.exports = {
  registerSocketServer,
};
```

Which is imported into my server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require("dotenv").config();

const socketServer = require("./socketServer");
const authRoutes = require("./routes/authRoutes");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || process.env.API_PORT;

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);

const server = http.createServer(app);
socketServer.registerSocketServer(server);

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL)
  .then(() => {
    server.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server is listening on ${PORT}`);
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Database connection failed. Server not started");
    console.error(err);
  });
```

On my frontend, I have a function just to connect to the socket Server:

```
import io from "socket.io-client";

let socket = null;

export const connectWithSocketServer = (userDetails) => {
  socket = io("http://localhost:5002");

  socket.on("connection", () => {
    console.log("succesfully connected with socket.io server");
    console.log(socket.id);
  });
};
```

Then I'm just calling that function in another component.

I have gone through multiple tutorials, all with more or less the same setup as above. Is there something I am missing or is this code outdated?

I was expecting a console.log to appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "connection" event is emitted on the server side when a new socket is connected, but on the client side, you should listen for the "connect" event. Try updating your frontend code as follows:

```
import io from "socket.io-client";

let socket = null;

export const connectWithSocketServer = (userDetails) => {
  socket = io("http://localhost:5002");

  socket.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("succesfully connected with socket.io server");
    console.log(socket.id);
  });
};
```

Now, when you call the **connectWithSocketServer** function in your component, you should see the expected console logs when the connection is established.

Answer (score 0):

In your frontend, instead of this:

```
socket = io("http://localhost:5002");
```

try this:

```
const socket = io("http://localhost:5002", {
  transports: ["websocket"],
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:5002"
  }
})
```

I was able to get sockets working in my app, but I use `python` as the backend. I'd be happy to share the backend code if you want to try and draw comparisons between the two.